# Get wishlist item's array

Tags: magento2, frontend, wishlist, customer-data

I made an add to wishlist with ajax module and I want to indicate if the product is already in wishlist without breaking the full page cache. I know the wishlist object is in `customer-data` but I can't get the Items from that object. Can you help me with some pointers?

js file code

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($, customerData, customer) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('test.wishlistChecker', {
        wishlistClass: 'in-wishlist',

        /** @inheritdoc */
        _create: function () {
            console.log('test checker');
            this.checkWishlistItems();
        },

        /**
         * Check customer wishlist
         */
        checkWishlistItems: function () {
            var wishlistItems = customerData.get('wishlist')['items'];

            console.log(wishlistItems);

        }
    });

    $(document).wishlistChecker();

    return $.test.wishlistChecker;
});
```

Comment: You only need to wishlist data?

Comment: I need to do it without "cachable=false" tag on xml block, this will break full page cache, so I need to get this information from customer data, an array of items in wishlist so I can add a different icon on items already in wishlist

Comment: @VladPatru Please share the code.

Comment: @PrincePatel Updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after some tests, the `js widget` version is not working every time so best sollution was to integrate with `uiComponent` as follows

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function (config, node) {
            this._super();

            this.wishlist = customerData.get('wishlist')();
            this.items = this.wishlist.items;
            var nodeRef = node.getAttribute('data-ref');


            if (this.items) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
                    var product = this.items[i];
                    if (nodeRef === product.product) {
                        node.className += " " + 'wishlist-full';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and I also added a new `data-ref` Attr to the `add-to-wishlist` action element that conains the `product_id`

thanks @Sohel Rana for the starting point

Answer (score 2):

**customer-data** updated via ajax, so it might not have the wishlist information at the initialization. Luckily **customer-data** use knockout observable functionality, so we can subscribe to data update event.

Check this sample. It tries to check the data on initialization and subscribe to update event at the same time.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data', 
    'domReady'
], function ($, Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            var _this = this;
            
            this._super();
            
            this.wishlist = customerData.get('wishlist');
            this.wishlist.subscribe(function(newValue) {
                _this.decorateItems();
            });

            _this.decorateItems();
        },
        
        decorateItems: function() {
                var items = this.wishlist().items;
            
                if (typeof items === 'undefined' || !items.length) return;
            
                $('a.action.towishlist').each(function(){
                        var data = $(this).data('post'),
                            i;
    
                        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                            if (data.data.product === items[i].product_id) {
                                $(this).addClass('selected');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
    });
});
```

Comment: here is full article with different examples - https://nwdthemes.com/2019/08/23/magento-2-working-with-wishlist/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at here: 
**vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/web/js/view/wishlist.js**

```
this.wishlist = customerData.get('wishlist');
```

But, it's just the general info about the wishlist items. The data doesn't have the product id or product sku.

Comment: I did that already but it returns an object, i need to get from that the items wich I couldn't get

Comment: I think it's easy to get. Please show me your code and update your question.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Can u pls guide me, thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/333497/57334

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
var wishlist = customerData.get('wishlist')();
if(wishlist.items) {
    var wishlistItems = wishlist.items;

    for (var i = 0; i < wishlistItems.length; i++) {
        var product = wishlistItems[i];
        console.log(product.product_name);
        console.log(product.image);
    }
}
```

Comment: not working, I still get the undefined output "TypeError: wishlistItems is undefined"

Comment: Check updated answer. It's working fine for M2.2.5